# google authenticator for certain users

Tags: ssh, authentication, google, pam, two-factor-authentication

After enabling Google authenticator (2 step authentication) on one of my testing servers running ubuntu 16.04 (LTS), I noticed I couldn't login anymore with a user who doesn't have a google authenticator profile on the server. I had to create a google authenticator profile (key) to let this user login.

My question now is:
would it be possible to have certain users use google authenticator and other users just SSH login without the google authenticator.

Detail:

user1 has a profile with google authenticator.

user2 doesn't have a profile with google authenticator.

user1 logs in through SSH, fills in his password and the code provide by the google authenticator app, he is able to login.

user2 logs in through SSH, fills in his password and is able to login (he doesn't need to enter a code.

It would be ideal to have 2 usergroups one that needs the google authenticator code and one that doesn't need it.

Answer (score 9):

Using the below solution, PAM Module(google authenticator) can be disable for specific users-

1) Create a user group on the Linux instance. MFA/PAM will be disabled for users present in this new group-

```
sudo groupadd <groupname>
```

2) Create User or add existing user to newly created group-

```
sudo useradd <username>
sudo usermod -a -G <groupname> <username>
```

3) Edit /etc/pam.d/sshd file and add the below statement to skip PAM module for the newly created group-

```
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup <groupname>
```

Optional-

If full access is required for this new group then add below line to visudo file-

```
%<groupname>ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

When a user will be created and added to the new group, MFA will be skipped for those users.

Referenced from - [TechManyu Blog](https://www.techmanyu.com/disable-linux-pam-module-for-specific-users/)

Comment: This answer saved me 3days of work

Comment: For `root` user even after adding it to the new group I created "no2fa" it is still asking for 2fa, this trick does work for any other user, but for root, is there any way to skip 2fa for root user?

Comment: This works for some applications, not all...
For example, workbench will still fail as the server checks the PAM authentication, after connecting through SSH.

Answer (score 2):

This might help: [Disable PAM module for group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864986/disable-pam-module-for-group).

You could place one user in a `google-authenticator` group and the other user in a `non-google-authenticator` group.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try, but [readme](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam) says you just may add "[nullok](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam#nullok)" option:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

Comment: yes, but nullok is not working, I can confirm for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: nullok works the first time a user logs in, not continously.

The docs state it's if a user hasn't set it up the first time.