# Disable PAM module for group

Tags: ssh, users, authentication, pam, groups

I recently enabled two-factor-authentication using google-authenticator on my SSH server. However I am now facing a problem:

I have a different group of users on my server which I am using for SFTP, but that group is no longer able to login since 2FA isn't set up for the users in the group. Is it possible to disable the google-authenticator module for that group? Enabling it for the users in the group is not an option because multiple users will be using this account.

PS: I use `openssh-server`

Comment: Answered in this comment- Hope it helps https://askubuntu.com/a/1051973/846342

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`pam_succeed_if`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pam_succeed_if.8) module (see manual page) before the `pam_google_authenticator` to skip this part for your group:

```
# the other authentication methods, such as @include common-auth
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup group
auth required pam_google_authenticator ...
```

Comment: It should probably be `[success=1 default=ignore]` instead of `required`. Right now, a user not in group will lead to the authentication failing, I think. `success=1` will make it skip the next method, `default=ignore` will mean users not in group will simply move on to the next method.

Comment: @muru yes, you are obviously right. Still learning the details and all the magic of the PAM stack :)

Comment: Is this dependent on whether you have multiple "AuthenticationMethods" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config ?  With the above line added, I still get 'Permission denied (keyboard-interactive)'

Comment: @Arj this means you have different configuration so this specific answere does not apply for you.

Answer (score 1):

Some SFTP clients can handle 2FA. For example, I'm using 2FA with FileZilla and WinSCP and they works. Also I have setup ssh-key authentication and it works alongside of 2FA.

However your question is interesting and I made a short survey. I found [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/57779/131156).

So, it is possible (and easy) to run separate ssh instances. I'm already tested it.

1. Make separate copies of `sshd_config` file.

   ```
   $ sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config_pwd
   $ sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config_2fa
   ```
2. Edit these new `config` files. One of the things you must change is the shh port. According to the example:

   2.a) `sshd_config_pwd` specific lines are:

   ```
   Port 1022
   ...
   PasswordAuthentication yes
   ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
   UsePAM no
   ```

   2.b) `sshd_config_2fa` specific lines are:

   ```
   Port 2022
   ...
   PasswordAuthentication no
   ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
   UsePAM yes
   ```
3. Open the necessary ports into the firewall. According to the example:

   ```
   $ sudo ufw limit 1022
   $ sudo ufw limit 2022
   ```
4. Run the new ssh instances:

   ```
   $ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_pwd
   $ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_2fa
   ```

That's it.

Comment: How is this answering the question? What you modify in the `sshd_config` to use different PAM stack and not use 2FA?

Comment: @Jakuje I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, so the point is "not using PAM". It might work in some cases, but PAM is not only about authentication, but also setting up session and lot more, therefore it might stop working from day to day. Also changing port is very confusing, especially if you want third party to connect to your server. Though yes, possible solution.

Comment: Yes, it's just a possible solution, which still incomplete, because I don't know elegant way to start these separate ssh instances at system startup.

Answer (score 0):

The following will make Google 2FA mandatory
for **all users**
*except* users belonging to the **sudo** and **admin** group 
(meaning if a user from group sudo or admin does not have 2FA configured, it will authenticate him/her based on their public key):

File: `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
auth optional pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup sudo
auth optional pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup admin
```

File: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

Results:

```
          |  Belongs to sudo or  |  Has 2FA Already Setup      |  Authentication Result
          |  admin group         |  in ~/.google_authenticator | 
----------+----------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------
User A    |          NO          |       NO                    | DENIED LOGIN UNTIL 2FA IS SETUP
User B    |          YES         |       NO                    | CAN LOGIN (PRIVATE/PUBLIC KEY USED)

User C    |          NO          |       YES                   | CAN LOGIN (PRIVATE/PUBLIC KEY AND 2FA USED)

User D    |          YES         |       YES                   | CAN LOGIN (PRIVATE/PUBLIC KEY AND 2FA USED)
```

According to [Google Authenticator's README.md Documentation](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam):

> **nullok**
>
> *PAM requires at least one SUCCESS answer from a module, and nullok causes this module to say IGNORE. This means that if this option is used at least one other module must have said SUCCESS. One way to do this is to add auth required pam_permit.so to the end of the PAM config.*

This makes the use of `nullok` here safe.